# Flutter BlocConsumer show loading dialog on button action

Tags: flutter, loading, flutter-bloc, bloc-consumer, loading-dialog

This is my "**EmployeePayrollInfoScreen"**

When I trigger download button. it will trigger **DownloadStubEvent**

```
stubAction: () {
 context.read<PersonalInfoBloc>().add(DownloadStubEvent(
 masterId: state.data?.payrollInfo?[index].payMasterId ?? 0,
 fiscalYear:state.data?.payrollInfo?[index].payMasterId ?? 2,));
 },
```

> **DownloadStubEvent** (state change sample)

```
emit(LoadingState()); // first start loading
final res = await ReportService().downloadStrubReport(); // get data 
emit(const HideLoadingState());  // download complete hide
```

> As a result  state change to **LoadingState** so body show **SizedBox()** widget. but i want when state is **LoadingState** (After click on download button) show list data not SizedBox().

***Thanks in advance***

```dart
class EmployeePayrollInfoScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const EmployeePayrollInfoScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<PersonalInfoBloc, PersonalInfoState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is LoadingState) {
          DialogHelper.showLoading(context: context);
          return;
        }

        if (state is HideLoadingState) {
          DialogHelper.hideLoading(context);
          return;
        }
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: ColorManager.bgColor,
          body: state is LoadedState
              ? Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(SizeManager.padding),
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        PrimaryContainer(
                          child: CurrentPayrollCardItem(
                            data: state.data?.currentPayroll,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const VerticalMargin(),
                        YtdCard(ytdInfo: state.data?.ytdInfo),
                        ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                            itemCount: state.data?.payrollInfo?.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return EmployeePayrollInfoItem(
                                data: state.data?.payrollInfo?[index],
                                stubAction: () {
                                  //=====> DOWNLOAD BUTTON <======
                                  context.read<PersonalInfoBloc>().add(DownloadStubEvent(
                                        masterId: state.data?.payrollInfo?[index].payMasterId ?? 0,
                                        fiscalYear:
                                            state.data?.payrollInfo?[index].payMasterId ?? 2,
                                      ));
                                },
                              );
                            })
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : const SizedBox(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code posted, the result you described is expected.

When you emit `LoadingState`, the `builder` will return `SizeBox` since `state is LoadedState` will return false.

I assume you want to show loading dialog on your loaded list. You can introduce a variable called `isLoading` into your `LoadedState`.

Change your bloc logic:

```
emit(LoadedState(isLoading = true)); // first start loading
final res = await ReportService().downloadStrubReport(); // get data 
emit(LoadedState(isLoading = false));  // download complete hide
```

Change your `listener`:

```
if (state.isLoading) {
    DialogHelper.showLoading(context: context);
} else {
    DialogHelper.hideLoading(context);
}
```